# Are there any places where should not use compressed public keys?

Tags: bitcoin-core, public-key

It is always worthwhile to use compressed keys to save size. Or somewhere in the Bitcoin code, exactly uncompressed keys are needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one advantage to use uncompressed key vs compressed.
So, there is no one place in code where uncompressed key is allowed and compressed key is disallowed

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#restrictions-on-public-key-type